# What method of data storage to use?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Requires implemented in application storage system.
You will be able to create projects. Projects are stored richtext and images. How best to implement the storage of the data in the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to give more information in your question, but it sounds like [Core Data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started) would suit your needs.

Comment: Downvoter please explain. I answered the OP's question to the extent that I could based on the limited background information he provided.

Comment: I would like to put to you a plus, but I already have merged into minus. And I do not understand this attitude. The question they do not like you see (